# Mysql: How reliable are values provided when rows are grouped?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I think this is a relatively advanced question and I may have trouble asking it well. so apologies in advance for any babbling.

I love Mysql's grouping functions. MIN(), MAX(), etc. make it easy to group rows by a certain common factor, then fetch salient features of each pool of grouped rows. But the question I'm asking relates to cases where I do *not* want this behavior to happen; rather, in a particular situation, I want to ensure that when I group a set of (let's say 10) rows into a single row, for any values that vary from row to row, all values displayed in the resultant grouped row were derived from *the same pre-grouped row*. My question: is this possible? are there potholes I should look out for?

Let me share a bit of this query's structure. At core, it has a "parent" table (here t1) joined to a "child" table (here t2). The query results, prior to any grouping or sorting, may list the same t1 record multiple times, associated with different t2 records and values. I want the final output to be grouped such that each t1 record only appears once, *and* that the t2 values displayed in each row reflect the t2 record that had the highest priority (among all t2 records associated with that t1 record). See my dumbed-down query below for example.

Based on my experimentation, it seems that nested queries should be able to do this, where I ORDER first, then GROUP later. The GROUP operation seems to reliably preserve the values from *the first row it came across*, meaning that if I ORDER then GROUP, I should have reasonable control over which values are included in the grouped output.

Here's an example of the query structure I'm planning. **My question:** Am I missing anything? Have you experienced GROUP to behave in ways that might make this a bad plan for me? Can you think of a simpler way to achieve what I'm describing?

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    # Each record from t1 may only appear once in the final output.
    t1.id, t1.field2, t1.field3, t1.field4,
    # there are multiple t2 records (each having different values & priority) 
    # associated with each t1 record.
    t2.id AS t2_id, t2.field5, t2.field6, t2.priority
  FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
    { several other joins }
  WHERE { lots of conditions }
  ORDER BY t2.priority ) t
GROUP BY t.priority
```

Comment: I would say that relying on MySQL's unusual behavior of permitting you to have columns in the `SELECT` list which are not also in the `GROUP BY` is _never_ a good idea.  It is generally not portable and will break on any other RDBMS (except maybe SQLite).  The non-grouped values it returns are essentially indeterminate, though it seems like most of the time it will return the "first" one it encounters.

Comment: why would you even group by anything when you're not using any aggregate function? Or is it your example that's inaccurate? If you just want to skip the repeated rows you only need the `distinct` keyword. Don't forget that `GROUP BY`, in mysql, also `order by asc` the results...

Comment: Completely unreliable. The opposite of reliable.

Comment: @Sebas, maybe I didn't make my example clear enough. The reason that I'm grouping is to eliminate duplicates, but I need to include data for one of several "child" rows based on the max value of a certain calculation (priority), which is difficult to perform in a subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **unreliable** at all. DBMS does not specify a row which will be returned in described case. To say more, it's only MySQL feature, in normal SQL this will be invalid - to mix non-group columns and group functions. Further explanations about this behavior can be found in [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) manual page:

> However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set
>   occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect
>   which values within each group the server chooses.

Comment: Thanks @Alma. I'm interested by the last sentence of that manual, which seems to deny that the (... (... ORDER BY n) GROUP BY n) structure I used above, is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

There's another way to get the right result that would work in any DBMS. Taking your original query, it would look something like this.

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.field2, t1.field3, t1.field4,
    t2.id AS t2_id, t2.field5, t2.field6, t2.priority
  FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id AND t2.priority = 
        (Select Max(t2b.priority) From t2 AS t2b Where t1.id = t2b.t1_id)
    { several other joins }
  WHERE { lots of conditions }
```

(I assumed there's only one row in t2 by (t1.id, priority) )

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Jhovanny. I think I simplified my example a bit too far... "priority" isn't actually a table column, it's a dynamic calculated value that is derived from a number of tables, so unfortunately this solution doesn't look hopeful to me.

Comment: @Topher I see what you mean. You could create a view and use in a manner similar to the one I used. If you want to post an example that's closer to what you need, I'd be glad to take a look.

Comment: Jhovanny, thanks for the offer. Based on all this helpful input, I took a careful look at my query and realized that one of the major factors in the "priority" value, could instead be outsourced to a separate calculation that happens beforehand and is stored in the DB with the relevant table. As a result, the calculation for "priority" has become simpler enough that these intricate grouping operations aren't needed any more. Psew!